# Как развернуть проект java с github

Tags: java, git

мне нужна библиотека MQTT для java.

Находится она здесь:
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java

К сожалению мне не удалось запустить встроенный тест.
Я в java совсем новичок.

Использую IDE eclipse.
Подскажите пожалуйста, может быть надо какие то утилиты поставить ?

Например, в php проект обычно разворачивают с помощью composer, в java может быть надо тоже что то применить ?

Comment: Есть разные сборщики проектов Gradle, Maven, Ant...

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт среда разработки?

Comment: тут даже до ошибок не доходит, вот тестовая программа:
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/
не может найти первую же библиотеку
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;

Comment: @Andrii Torzhkov можете сказать - что тут используется? maven ?

Comment: @ГайратВласов, да, библиотеку можно подключить с помощью сборщика [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), добавив зависимость в POM файл проекта Java

Comment: У вас в проекте pom.xml. Соответсвенно у вас проект на maven.

Comment: И лучше используйте Intellij IDEA, она многое за вас порешает, чего ен сделает Eclipse без плагинов.

Comment: @Andrii Torzhkov , спасибо! Почти получилось :) Поставил Intellij IDEA бесплатную версию с поддержкой maven. При сборке проекте выдал: Error:(568, 63) java: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement) на строке <br> catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e). Я в settings полазил - у меня везде JDK 8 стоит - или это вопрос не к нему?

Comment: У вас консольное приложение или web?

Comment: Попробуйте зайти в Project Structure -> Modules. Пройдите по всем модулям и поставьте language level: 7(или 8). По идее должно решить вашу проблему.

Comment: @Andrii Torzhkov , огромное Вам спасибо за ценные советы! Ошибка ушла. Долго искал диалог - оказывается надо нажать Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее часто используемыми сборщиками проектов, как уже уточнял в комментариях [Andrii Torzhkov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/302329/andrii-torzhkov), являются Maven, Gradle и Ant. Чтобы подключить библиотеку в проект нужно добавить зависимость, используя pom.xml файл.

Обычно при создании maven проекта, такой файл сам генерируется и Вам остается лишь добавить в него свои зависимости, необходимые для проекта.

В IDE eclipse  структура maven-проекта такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как Ваша библиотека может быть [подключена](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java#using-the-paho-java-client) с помощью Maven, то я Вам рекомендую с ним ознакомиться [здесь](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо все откликнувшимся!
И в особенности Andrii Torzhkov, давшим нужные советы.

Лучше всего оказалось воспользоваться Intellij IDEA  (в данном случае я выбрал бесплатную версию тем более что она поддерживает maven)

Для сборки проектов JAVA применяются разные сборщики, конкретно для этого проекта был применен maven (он уже интегрирован в Intellij IDEA )

Для корректной работы не забудьте правильно настроить файл pom.xml

Для maven нужно чтобы исходные файлы лежали в директории src/main/java
Возможно что это настраивается, но в данном проекте они так и располагались.

Дополнительно потребуется настроить Language Level - Грубо говоря это версия JDK
В настоящий момент доступна 8 версия (правильно 1.8). Изначально в настройках проекта стояла 5 версия - что не дало возможности собрать проект.

Для настройки надо открыть диалог Project Structure - для этого надо нажать Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S (почему то через меню я вызвать диалог не смог)
Далее надо зайти в Modules и установить Language level на 7 или 8.

Проект собирается через меню : Build/Build Project